# Using pseudo-hydrogen in VASP results in the wrong format in CONTCAR

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software-assistance

I am using VASP to do the simulation of a slab, I used some pseudohydrogen to passivate the bottom side of the slab. After the structure optimization calculation, the `CONTCAR` I get looks like this:

```
 TiO2_mp-2657_slab_unitcell             
   1.0000000000000000     
     2.9691998959000001    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    6.5806999206999999    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   38.4453010559000035
   Ti   O    H.   H1
     8    16     1     1
```

The original `POSCAR` is:

```
 TiO2_mp-2657_slab_unitcell             
   1.0000000000000000     
     2.9691998959000001    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    6.5806999206999999    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   38.4453010559000035
   Ti   O    H.66   H1.33
     8    16     1     1
```

As shown above, the `H.66` and `H1.33` turn into `H.` and `H1`. Is this just a small bug of the input/output, or is it gonna affect the calculation results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I am fairly certain that line of the CONTCAR technically doesn't matter. If you put a O instead of H, but put the potentials in the right order, you will get the right result even though the element is wrong. For visualization, it will definitely be wrong but I don't think the calculated result is wrong.

In tools such as ASE the potentials are derived from this line of the POSCAR though, so be careful.